# Getting text inside p-element Selenium/java xpath

Tags: java, testing, xpath, selenium, junit

I am trying to do some test using Selenium and I am facing some problems. 
Suppose I have the following:

```
 <p>
   <label for="something">whatever :</label>
   what I really want
 </p>
```

I would like to be able to get only text what I really want, instead of all texts inside p-element
Getting text inside label is possible by doing :

```
 selenium.getText("//p/label[@for='something']");
```

Does anyone know how to get only in my case "what I really want"

Thanks!

Comment: Im not good at xpaths but shouldnt something like: getText("xpath=X"), where X is xpath to p work?

Comment: Better use **WebDriver** if you can choose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`//p[label[@for = 'something']]/text()[normalize-space()]` is an XPath expression selecting a node-set (XPath 1.0) or sequence (XPath 2.0) of direct text child nodes of that `p` element. In your sample there is only one such child node.